Passport.js Error Handling Instead of throwing the error into stdout
So I Have The Current Code For Authorization (and im probably going to merge login with signup):
Strategy:


const passport = require("passport")
const { Strategy } = require("passport-local")
const { getUserByUsername, getUserById } = require("./database/interactors/user")
const { comparePasswords } = require("./utils/hashing")

passport.serializeUser(( user, done ) => {
  done(null, user.dbid.toString())
})

passport.deserializeUser(async ( id, done ) => {
  try {
    const user = await getUserById(id)
  
    if(!user){
      throw new Error("ERR_USER_NOTFOUND_AUTHED")
    }

    done(null, user)
  } catch (err) {
    done(err, null)
  }
})

module.exports = passport.use(
  new Strategy({}, async ( username, password, done ) => {
    try {
      const user = await getUserByUsername(username, true)
      
      if(!comparePasswords(password, user.password)) throw new Error("ERR_PASSWORD_WRONG")
      
      done(null, user)
    } catch (err) {
      done(err, null)
    }
  })
)



Route:


const LOGGER_NAME = "Auth Router"

// A LOT of imports were here

const router = Router()
log(LOGGER_NAME, " Router Is Up")

router.post("/",
  checkSchema(auth_base, ["body"]),
  inputValidator,
  passport.authenticate("local"),
  ( req, res ) => {
    res.sendStatus(200)
})

router.post("/signup",
  checkSchema(auth_base, ["body"]),
  inputValidator,
  /**
   * 
   * @param {import("express").Request} req 
   * @param {import("express").Response} res 
   * @returns 
   */
  async ( req, res ) => {
    const { body } = req

    if(req.user) return res.status(400).send(generateJSONError({ msg: "ERR_AUTHORIZED", path: ""}))
    if(await getUserByUsername(body["username"], false, false)) return res.status(400).send(generateJSONError({ msg: "ERR_USERNAME_EXISTS", path: "username"}))

    try {
      const user = await createUser(body["username"], hashPassword(body["password"]))

      res.status(201).send(user)
    }catch(err){
      res.status(400).send(generateJSONError({ msg: "ERR_UNEXPECTED", path: ""}))
      throw err
    }
})

router.get("/status", ( req, res ) => {
  if(req.user) return res.status(200).send(req.user)
  res.sendStatus(401)
})

router.post("/logout",
  requiresAuth,
  ( req, res ) => {
    req.logOut({}, err => {
      if(err) return res.sendStatus(500)
      
      return res.sendStatus(200)
    })
})

module.exports = router



The Problem Is That This Code Throws The Error Directly And Does Not Let Me Handle It (i want to convert it to json and send it to the user)
btw if the response has a status code of 400 or 500, will AXIOS return it in the .then or .catch ?

If Any Additional Information Are Needed, Im Here

Hi, Do you mean the app crashes by unhandled exception ? if so, please see which is the statement it is failing, you may able to use the stack trace and find it.
